# GUI for writing HDL and viewing simulation?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, verilog

I am a software developer and I'd like to code for FPGAs. Prior to buying an FPGA I thought it might be better to obtain a simulator where I could practice my HDL and see whether I can get the hang of it all.

What would be the best GUI for writing VHDL and being able to see what the code would actually do if it were flashed to an FPGA?

If the simulator could allow me to drag & drop common library components that would be great.

Any other advice regarding this is most-welcome.

Comment: "Best" is probably open to question, but you can download the tools from either [Xilinx](http://www.xilinx.com/products/design-tools/vivado/vivado-webpack.html) or [Altera](http://dl.altera.com/?edition=lite) (or smaller players like [Microsemi](http://www.microsemi.com/products/fpga-soc/design-resources/design-software/libero-soc)) for free.

Comment: If you are a SW developer my best advice is this: Understand you are not going to 'code' in VHDL. You are going to describe HW. It is a completely different thing.

Comment: @ClaudioAviChami I don't even wish to write Verilog or VHDL if I am honest. I would rather build the circuitry using digital components in a GUI.

Comment: @user997112 well you missed by some 20 years... The days of using digital discrete components are long gone. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from things that you will never be able to afford as single person or small company:

As it is now, FPGAs pretty much pose a vendor lock-in. You buy an Altera FPGA, you're damned to use Quartus. You buy a Xilinx FPGA, you're going to use Vivado (or ISE, if the FPGA bought is not among those supported by Vivado).

Pretty much everyone hates something about these GUIs. And many argue that this is not coincidential: To be really good at say Vivado, you need to spend years using it. Once you've done that, you'll not buy an Altera FPGA for your next project.

Now, there's currently an upcoming toolchain composed of Free & Open Source Software for Lattice's ICE FPGA. Check out Yosys and it's ecosystem!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the vendor specific tools. The two main FPGA vendors are Altera and Xilinx. I am familiar with Altera only and Quartus is their development package. Quartus has a free version. You can compile and synthesize HDL and simulate it in ModelSim. You will need to write your code so it is synthesizable, which is always a good thing. Alternatively, you can use Xilinx and their tools.

If you want something light weight and command line you can use ghdl as well, but I don't think that is what you want.

Comment: Hi, are you sure Quartus is free? I downloaded and it said I either have to buy a licence or a 31 day evaluation period?

Comment: Yes, there is a free version. There are three versions in total, the first is free.